# PICOS library python

Tags: python, picos-api

I am trying to multiply two matrices, in one I have a multidimensional values of sixe (96, 96, 2, 1) and I am trying to multiply it with an array of PICOS variables, it is possible to do this?? because the error that I have is: picos.valuable.NotValued: Mutable input is not valued.
I have tried everything I had in mind. Any expert can help me?

Thank you

Comment: could you post the code of what you have tried and the error you are getting?

Comment: No nom I am going to explain me sorry. Lets imagine that I have any problem already written. The thing that I want it in the standard form. A matricial form. It looks like next, in which A, b... are matrix.

Comment: Max z = c' x
subject to:
Ax = b
x ≥ 0.

Comment: We don't need explanations. We need the code that is giving you the error with the input matrices you are giving and the expected result